# ajax function doesn't work when referred to from instagram

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

My function seems to return nothing for the destination element when the link is referred to from Instagram. It works fine if I directly visit the page.

```
 function getTeamsByLeague(league) {
        //console.log("League Set: " + league);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo SITE_BASE_URL; ?>json.php",
            data: {method: "getteamsbyregion", league: league},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data && data.length > 0) {
                    $("#destination").empty();
                    var selected = "";
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                        if (item.team == teamSelected) {
                            selected = " selected";
                            $("#latitude").val(item.lat);
                            $("#longitude").val(item.lng);
                        } else {
                            selected = "";
                        }
                        $("#destination").append('<option ' + selected + ' value="' + item.lat + ',' + item.lng + '">' + item.team + '</option>');
                        if (index == 0) {
                            $("#latitude").val(item.lat);
                            $("#longitude").val(item.lng);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
```

Comment: what exactly does *"referred to from Instagram"* mean? If you are running that script on instagram domain you need to enable CORS in your php

Comment: Do you successfully getting a Json response?

Comment: It's linked from an IG profile

Comment: linked from a profile doesn't tell us anything meaningful

Comment: Yes, the function before it successfully returns the league names (it's meant to collate league names in one <select> then team names in another for each corresponding league

Comment: Script is run on my own domain, my IG account links to my domain. Otherwise I don't understand the question

Comment: what does *"links to my domain"* mean? If you aren't on your page as mentioned in question...where are you when you run this code?

Comment: The code runs perfectly when I type in www.myurl.com directly but when I click the link on Instagram www.myurl.com it does not work.

Comment: You need to provide a proper explanation of this link and how it works and where it goes to. These little tidbits are not making it easy to understand your problem or what instagram has to do with it